# save form values through script file in umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

hello i want to save the value of umbraco form in database for this i have made script file and in this script file i have created function to save data and called this function in same script file and this script file is used in macro and i have called this macro in template of my page but it is not working will this approach is proper or i have to something else my basic aim is to save data in database without creating my usercontrol

code is

```
@functions
{
    public void AddToCart()
    {
        string con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["umbracoDbDSN"].ToString();
        SqlConnection OnCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["umbracoDbDSN"].ToString());
        ItemsDataContext db = new ItemsDataContext(con);
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        string itemcode= request.Form["ItemCode"].ToString();
        string itemname = request.Form["ItemName"].ToString();
        string itemcategory = Request.Form["ItemCategory"].ToString();
        string userid = "Pallavi";
        db.sp_AddItems(userid, itemcode, itemcategory, itemname, 0);


        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = "Pallavi";
    }
}


@if (!IsPost)
{
    AddToCart();
}
```

and called this macro on template

```
<umbraco:Macro Alias="Uc_Cart" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
```

Answer (score 6):

You approach is wrong. You must use the methods that Umbraco provides in their API and do not try to write data into the database directly.

Try this code to create an new document from Razor code:

```
@using umbraco.BusinessLogic;
@using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web;
@{
    DocumentType dt = DocumentType.GetByAlias("Textpage"); 
    User author = umbraco.BusinessLogic.User.GetUser(0); 
    Document doc = Document.MakeNew("My new document", dt, author, parentID); 
}
```

The example above is for Umbraco 4.x. If you're using Umbraco v6.x you could also use the new API methods:

```
@{
    // get an instance of the contentService
    var contentService = ApplicationContext.Services.ContentService;
    // create new content, the last param is the userId and is optional [default = 0]
    IContent newContent = contentService.CreateContent("My new document", parentID, "Textpage", 0);
    // set property values
    newContent.SetValue("propertyAlias", "Value");
    // save (or save and publish)
    contentService.Save(newContent);
}
```

Comment: The last parameter in the MakeNew method is the parentID of the Document. It is saved as a childItem of this parent. If you want the document to be saved in the root, use -1 as parentID

Comment: in the example the author is fetched by using the authorID in het User.GetUser(id) method. If you use 0, you get the Admin user, or you can use the ID of any other existing user.

Comment: i m not getting getuser method in my application and what the prob find is my form is not posting so what can i do

Comment: I modified the original code and used the namespace for the User object, also added an example if you are using Umbraco V6.x

Comment: i dont want to create a new document simply i want to access this document type control values and save it

Comment: Where do you want to save your data? If you want to save it inside Umbraco as content items, you need to follow my approach. If you want to save it in a separate database, you need to get the connectionstring of your database and use a query to add it.